# how to create mock for Date method within controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

```
$scope.deleteAbc = ->
  alert("xyz")
```

how do I get the value of the alert when this method is call from test.

```
describe "XYZ", ->
  $scope = null
  $controller  = null
  beforeEach inject ($rootScope,$controller) ->
    $scope = $rootScope
    ctrl = $controller("StatusController",
      $scope: $scope
    )
```

Comment: The project [`Timecop`](https://github.com/jamesarosen/Timecop.js) can be used during unit tests to freeze or change time created by `new Date()` calls and might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking alert() you can inject AngularJS's $window into your controller and invoke $window.alert().

The you are able to fake the $window object in your test. The alerted variable contains the alerted message.

```
describe "XYZ", ->
  $scope = null
  $controller  = null
  alerted = null
  beforeEach inject ($rootScope,$controller) ->
    $scope = $rootScope
    $window:
      alert: (message) ->
        alerted = message
    ctrl = $controller("StatusController",
      $scope: $scope
      $window: $window
    )
```